# why does this program continue, printing out "understood, now restate points", even if I enter y for the (tf) variable

Tags: python

Here's the code:

```py
x = float(input("x1 = "))

y = float(input("y1 = "))

print ("your first point is " + str(x) + ", " + str(y))

tx = float(input("x2 = "))

ty = float(input("y2 = "))

print ("your second point is " + str(tx) + ", " + str(ty))

rise = ty / y

run = tx / x

slope = rise / run

tf = str(input("is these the correct points? - " + str(x) + "," + str(y) + " - " + str(tx) + "," + str(ty) + ": "))

if tf == str("yes") or str("Yes") or str("Y") or str("y") or str("oui"):
    rise = ty / y

run = tx / x

slope = rise / run

if x == tx:
    print("vertical line - slope underfined")

elif y == ty:
    print("horizontal line, slope = 0")

else:
    print ("slope of line is " + str(slope))


if tf == str("no") or str("No") or str("NO") or str("n") or str("N") or str("non"):
    print("understood, now restate points")
    x = float(input("x1 = "))

y = float(input("y1 = "))

print ("your first point is " + str(x) + ", " + str(y))

tx = float(input("x2 = "))

ty = float(input("y2 = "))

print ("your second point is " + str(tx) + ", " + str(ty))

rise = ty / y

run = tx / x

slope = rise / run

if x == tx:
    print("vertical line - slope underfined")

elif y == ty:
    print("horizontal line, slope = 0")

else:
    print ("slope of line is " + str(slope))
```

I expected it to end the program after entering `"y"` or `"yes"`, but it continues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your `if` conditions are not correct. When comparing a variable with multiple possibilities, you should `==` for each one or use `in` with the list or tuple of possible values after it.

By the way, you don't need to wrap string with `str()` in python. So `str("hello")` and `"hello"` are the same.

Updated code:

```py
x = float(input("x1 = "))
y = float(input("y1 = "))
print("your first point is " + str(x) + ", " + str(y))

tx = float(input("x2 = "))
ty = float(input("y2 = "))
print("your second point is " + str(tx) + ", " + str(ty))

rise = ty / y
run = tx / x
slope = rise / run

tf = input("is these the correct points? - " + str(x) + "," + str(y) + " - " + str(tx) + "," + str(ty) + ": ")

if tf in ("yes", "Yes", "Y", "y", "oui"):
    rise = ty / y

run = tx / x
slope = rise / run

if x == tx:
    print("vertical line - slope underfined")
elif y == ty:
    print("horizontal line, slope = 0")
else:
    print("slope of line is " + str(slope))

if tf in ("no", "No", "NO", "n", "N", "non"):
    print("understood, now restate points")
    x = float(input("x1 = "))

y = float(input("y1 = "))
print("your first point is " + str(x) + ", " + str(y))

tx = float(input("x2 = "))
ty = float(input("y2 = "))
print("your second point is " + str(tx) + ", " + str(ty))

rise = ty / y
run = tx / x
slope = rise / run

if x == tx:
    print("vertical line - slope underfined")
elif y == ty:
    print("horizontal line, slope = 0")
else:
    print("slope of line is " + str(slope))
```